# Find the closest radio button which is not disabled and checked it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have code as:

```js
let aid = 1;

if($("#ar_"+aid+" .radio input:checked").is(':disabled')){
    $("#ar_"+aid).closest('.radio input').is(':enabled').attr("checked",true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="background:#c3c3c3" id="t_1">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_1">
            <td>
                <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="base_cat_1" id="am_1" value="1" disabled>
                    <label for="am_1">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
                    <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox_am_1">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Amenity 1
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_2">
            <td>
                <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="base_cat_1" id="am_2" value="1" disabled>
                    <label for="am_2">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
                    <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_2" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox_am_2">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Amenity 2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_3">
            <td>
                <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="base_cat_1" id="am_3" value="1">
                    <label for="am_3">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
                    <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_3" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox_am_3">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Amenity 3
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_4">
            <td>
                <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="base_cat_1" id="am_4" value="1" disabled>
                    <label for="am_4">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
                    <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_4" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox_am_4">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Amenity 4
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="t_2">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_5">
            <td>
                <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="base_cat_2" id="am_5" value="1">
                    <label for="am_5">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
                    <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_5" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox_am_5">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Amenity 5
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_6">
            <td>
                <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="base_cat_2" id="am_6" value="1">
                    <label for="am_6">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
                    <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_6" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox_am_6">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Amenity 6
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_7">
            <td>
                <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="base_cat_2" id="am_7" value="1" disabled>
                    <label for="am_7">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
                    <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_7" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox_am_7">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Amenity 7
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_8">
            <td>
                <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="base_cat_2" id="am_8" value="1" disabled>
                    <label for="am_8">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
                    <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_8" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox_am_8">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Amenity 8
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="t_3" style="background:lime">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_9">
            <td>
                <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="base_cat_3" id="am_9" value="1" disabled>
                    <label for="am_9">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
                    <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_9" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox_am_9">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Amenity 9
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_10">
            <td>
                <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="base_cat_3" id="am_10" value="1" disabled>
                    <label for="am_10">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
                    <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_10" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox_am_10">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Amenity 10
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_11">
            <td>
                <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="base_cat_3" id="am_11" value="1" disabled>
                    <label for="am_11">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
                    <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_11" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox_am_11">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Amenity 11
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_12">
            <td>
                <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
                    <input type="radio" name="base_cat_3" id="am_12" value="1" disabled>
                    <label for="am_12">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
                    <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_12" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
                    <label for="checkbox_am_12">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Amenity 12
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here, I have lists of radio buttons. So, at first I will have `a id`, in this case I have considered that id as `1`. Now, I want to do the following things:

- check if the radio button with id `ar_+aid` is disabled (already done)
- if it is disabled find the next radio button which is not disabled (i.e, radio button with the same name) of this case the third (ar_3) should be is the closest one, however, it shouldn't go to another radio group.
- if every radio button is disabled just console the message, that all are disabled. (i.e if I pass id 11, this should throw an error as all 12,9 and 10 are disabled)

How could I achieve it? Let me know if you need anything more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `name` attribute of radio buttton to find the input which is not disabled using `$("input[name=" + name + "]:not(:disabled):first")` which will checked if the radio with `name` is not disable and get the `:first` input while searching then you can use `.prop('checked', true)` to add `checked` attribute to that radio button.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
let aid = 1;
//get name of radio
var name = $("#ar_" + aid + " .radio input").attr("name");
//check if disable
if ($("#ar_" + aid + " .radio input").is(':disabled')) {
  var count = 0;
  //get the rado button whch is not disable
  $("input[name=" + name + "]:not(:disabled):first").each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', true) //prop true
    count++;
  })
  if (count == 0) {
    console.log("All disable....")
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="background:#c3c3c3" id="t_1">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_1">
      <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
          <input type="radio" name="base_cat_1" id="am_1" value="1" disabled>
          <label for="am_1">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
          <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
          <label for="checkbox_am_1">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Amenity 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_2">
      <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
          <input type="radio" name="base_cat_1" id="am_2" value="1" disabled>
          <label for="am_2">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
          <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_2" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
          <label for="checkbox_am_2">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Amenity 2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_3">
      <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
          <input type="radio" name="base_cat_1" id="am_3" value="1">
          <label for="am_3">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
          <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_3" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
          <label for="checkbox_am_3">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Amenity 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_4">
      <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
          <input type="radio" name="base_cat_1" id="am_4" value="1" disabled>
          <label for="am_4">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
          <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_4" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
          <label for="checkbox_am_4">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Amenity 4
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="t_2">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_5">
      <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
          <input type="radio" name="base_cat_2" id="am_5" value="1">
          <label for="am_5">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
          <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_5" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
          <label for="checkbox_am_5">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Amenity 5
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_6">
      <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
          <input type="radio" name="base_cat_2" id="am_6" value="1">
          <label for="am_6">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
          <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_6" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
          <label for="checkbox_am_6">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Amenity 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_7">
      <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
          <input type="radio" name="base_cat_2" id="am_7" value="1" disabled>
          <label for="am_7">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
          <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_7" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
          <label for="checkbox_am_7">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Amenity 7
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_8">
      <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
          <input type="radio" name="base_cat_2" id="am_8" value="1" disabled>
          <label for="am_8">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
          <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_8" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
          <label for="checkbox_am_8">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Amenity 8
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="t_3" style="background:lime">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_9">
      <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
          <input type="radio" name="base_cat_3" id="am_9" value="1" disabled>
          <label for="am_9">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
          <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_9" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
          <label for="checkbox_am_9">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Amenity 9
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_10">
      <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
          <input type="radio" name="base_cat_3" id="am_10" value="1" disabled>
          <label for="am_10">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
          <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_10" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
          <label for="checkbox_am_10">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Amenity 10
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_11">
      <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
          <input type="radio" name="base_cat_3" id="am_11" value="1" disabled>
          <label for="am_11">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
          <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_11" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
          <label for="checkbox_am_11">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Amenity 11
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="amenities-row" id="ar_12">
      <td>
        <div class="radio radio-info pl-2">
          <input type="radio" name="base_cat_3" id="am_12" value="1" disabled>
          <label for="am_12">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-info pl-2">
          <input name="selected_am" id="checkbox_am_12" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
          <label for="checkbox_am_12">
                    </label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        Amenity 12
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Swati. Please don't mind if I mention you on my future jquery question. By the way, more than the first I was looking for the next(), and if the element is the last one next should be the first child. Will it work for that case?

Comment: Hi, something like this should work.. i.e :`$("#ar_" + aid + " .radio input").closest('table').find("input[name=" + name + "]:not(:disabled):first").prop('checked', true)` not sure .. test it at your end and let me know .